# Where did my bad question go? I need a link from the comments.

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation

I asked a question about "Why pokemon is popular". Granted, it's a terribly subjective question and probably terrible altogether, but in the comments, someone posted a useful pair of links. I understand why the question migt have been deleted, but **can I please get the links posted here?** Even better would be to have the question undeleted and then locked/protected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the links

http://w3.salemstate.edu/~poehlkers/Emerson/Pokemon.html

http://www.br-online.de/jugend/izi/english/research/e_pokemon.htm